# PHP Wordpress: Where does print_r() output to in Safari?

Tags: php, wordpress, safari

If I execute

```
print_r('Hello');
```

on a Wordpress code snippet, where would this actually print? I'm using Safari.

Comment: Somewhere on the page. Try it and see.

Comment: Your web browser does not matter.  that code (PHP) is executed on the server.  it should print 'Hello' and any client (safari, firefox, curl from command line, etc) would see 'Hello'.

Answer (score 0):

print_r in php typically prints in the parent node of the node you placed the code within.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didnt give more information i assume that
this is the php print_r.

So its most likely that the output will be in the middle of your HTML code or your snippet.

You should find it in the HTML source and maybe also see it on the website